# Django: caching w.r.t url and also reflect changes

Tags: django

In Django i have an url which does some calculations based on dynamic data.

So if i cache the url then will it return the updated results if there are any changes on dynamic data.

Eg: Like purchasing.

User adds list of items he wants.

I have a page  `localhost/user/items/` which will display all the list of items he added and also with a link `localhost/user/items/specs` to display the specifications of all the items he added.

Showing the `localhost/user/items/` page takes less time.

But `localhost/user/items/specs` takes a lot of time.

How can I cache `localhost/user/items/specs` and also reflect any changes

Comment: This should completely depend on your applications caching mechanism. Try to check a few articles (around memcached): 
1. https://medium.com/@netfluff/memcached-for-django-ecedcb74a06d 
2. https://www.peterbe.com/plog/fastest-cache-backend-possible-for-django
3. https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/24/django-memcached-optimizing-django-through-caching/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of digging into the source code i found how to show cache pages if data is not updated else show the modified data view

```
from django.middleware.cache import CacheMiddleware

@login_required

someview(request, slug=None)

    ######  data_updated
    # Check the conditions data modified is updated or not
    data_updated = True/False
    ######

    cachemiddleware = CacheMiddleware(cache_timeout=60*15)

    if data_updated:

        #######
            # RUN all the code for view
            # response = ..........
        #######


        # this is required because if the url is already cached it will be false
        request._cache_update_cache = True

        return cachemiddleware.process_response(request, response)

    else:

        result = cachemiddleware.process_request(request)

        if result is not None:
            return result
        else:

            #######
            # RUN all the code for view
            # response = ..........
            #######

            return cachemiddleware.process_response(request, response)
```